# get specified indexes of pandas dataframe where column has condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
id    value
14     122
15     120
16     190
17     490
18     328
19     309
20     323
```

I have a list of id's `L = [14,17,20]` and want to do two things:

> Get the list of indexes of those rows where for the id's is not in the list L
>
> i.e.( index of rows 15,16,18,19)

and,

> Delete the rows for the id's is not in the list L.

My expected output:

```
id    value
14     122
17     490
20     323
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), for inverting boolean mask `~`:

```
idx = df.index[~df['id'].isin(L)].tolist()
print (idx)
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

and then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1 = df.drop(idx)
print (df1)
   id  value
0  14    122
3  17    490
6  20    323
```

Alternative:

```
df1 = df[df['id'].isin(L)]
print (df1)
   id  value
0  14    122
3  17    490
6  20    323
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution:

```
In [106]: df.query("id in @L")
Out[106]:
   id  value
0  14    122
3  17    490
6  20    323
```